# Request Entity Too Large Error from CDN When WFFM form Submitted

Tags: wffm, cdn

Our site is set up to access through a CDN.

When a WFFM Form is submitted with image sizes of 3MB, it returns a "413 Request Entity Too Large" status error.

I have found, in online documentation, that this error may suggest a file upload limit of the CDN, but our hosting provider has told us that it is a result of too much information in the `Request Payload` headers from the WFFM submission. He has recommended that we try to trim the headers on form submission requests.

i.e.

[image]

Does this sound like it could be the issue? Any details to help explain the issue or to help with actually trimming these headers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from one of my colleague about this issue

So basically the suggestion made by the hosting provider about Request Header size is incorrect.

There is a defined limit for Request Headers in CloudFront

> The limit is at 20,480 bytes (Maximum length of a request, including
>   headers and query strings) >
>
> - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244883/cloudfront-responds-with-a-status-of-413-request-entity-too-large

But, Request Payload is not a part of the Request Header. Our request header size is in normal range.